# Matlab: In function "fminsearch(fun,x0)" x0 not getting accepted as matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-functions

In Matlab documentation for function [fminsearch(fun,x0)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fminsearch.html) , `x0` can be a scalar, vector, or matrix. However I am trying to call this function as :

```
weight=2;
delta_obj=@(k_to_perturb_annealing) gibbs_sampling_sisim_well_testing(k_to_perturb_annealing);
k_to_perturb_annealing=fminsearch(delta_obj,k_to_perturb_annealing_initial);
```

Where, **k_to_perturb_annealing_initial** is 101x82 matrix. I am getting stuck with an error on line **k_to_perturb_annealing=fminsearch(delta_obj,k_to_perturb_annealing_initial);**

**Error Message:**

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in ==> fminsearch at 195
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
Error in ==> optimizing_by_perturbing_SISIM_perm at
31
k_to_perturb_annealing=fminsearch(delta_obj,k_to_perturb_annealing_initial);
```

The function **gibbs_sampling_sisim_well_testing(k_to_perturb_annealing)** I am calling above is:

```
function[obj_fun]=gibbs_sampling_sisim_well_testing(k_to_perturb_annealing)

%% Well parameters

nCell=40000;
A=((sqrt(nCell)*500*sqrt(nCell)*500))/43560; % Area of reservoir in acres
Nw=5; % Number of production wells
xy_wells=[170,130,70,40,20;50,125,190,100,20]; % 1st and 2nd rows represent x and y coordinates respectively
r_investigation=sqrt((A*43560)/(pi*Nw)); % in ft
r_inv_cells=ceil(r_investigation/500);

%% Loading the well testing permeability values for both drawdown and buildup

k_well_testing_dd_sisim=load('k_well_testing_dd_sisim');
k_well_testing_bup_sisim=load('k_well_testing_bup_sisim');

k_dd=struct2cell(k_well_testing_dd_sisim);
k_dd=k_dd{1};

k_bup=struct2cell(k_well_testing_bup_sisim);
k_bup=k_bup{1};

%% Computing the k_eff using well testing perms and k_geomean using reference model of SISIM simulated perms

%# Computing effective permeability value from well testing
k_eff=mean([mean(k_dd),mean(k_bup)]);

%# geomean value of permeability is taken as geomean of 2 times r_inv_cells perm values in X and Y direction around well 1
k_geomean=geomean(geomean(k_to_perturb_annealing));

%# Storing the coordinates of k_to_perturb_annealing

x=max(xy_wells(1,1)-r_inv_cells,1):min(xy_wells(1,1)+r_inv_cells,sqrt(nCell));
y=max(xy_wells(2,1)-r_inv_cells,1):min(xy_wells(2,1)+r_inv_cells,sqrt(nCell));

for i=1:length(x)
    xcoord_k_to_perturb_annealing(1:length(y),i)=x(i);
    ycoord_k_to_perturb_annealing(1:length(y),i)=y;
end

xcoord_k_to_perturb_annealing=reshape(xcoord_k_to_perturb_annealing,(length(y)*length(x)),1);
ycoord_k_to_perturb_annealing=reshape(ycoord_k_to_perturb_annealing,(length(y)*length(x)),1);

%# Changing the gridded k_to_perturb_annealing to a vector form
vector_k_to_perturb_annealing=reshape(k_to_perturb_annealing,(length(y)*length(x)),1);

%% Reading perm_sampledata_for_annealing from gslib .dat file using `gslib_file_to_mat_general.mat' function

nModel_sampledata=3;
nCell_sampledata=20;
nModel_want_sampledata=3;
[perm_sampledata_for_annealing]=gslib_file_to_mat_general(nModel_sampledata,nCell_sampledata,nModel_want_sampledata,'perm_sampledata_5wells_sisim_for_annealing_gslib_format');

%# Separating the contents of file perm values and their coordinates
xcoord_perm_sampledata_for_annealing=perm_sampledata_for_annealing(:,1);
ycoord_perm_sampledata_for_annealing=perm_sampledata_for_annealing(:,2);
values_perm_sampledata_for_annealing=perm_sampledata_for_annealing(:,3);
%% Using variogram.mat function to compute variogram values and lag distances

%# for perm_sampledata_for_annealing

variogram_perm_sampledata=variogram([xcoord_perm_sampledata_for_annealing ycoord_perm_sampledata_for_annealing],values_perm_sampledata_for_annealing,'plotit',false,'nrbins',50,'anisotropy',true);
variogram_perm_sampledata=struct2cell(variogram_perm_sampledata);
gamma_perm_sampledata=variogram_perm_sampledata{1};
theta_perm_sampledata=(variogram_perm_sampledata{2})*(180/pi);
h_perm_sampledata=variogram_perm_sampledata{4};

%# for k_to_perturb_annealing

memory_cells=randperm(2000); % due to lack of memory space, have to use maximum of 2000 points
variogram_k_to_perturb_annealing=variogram([xcoord_k_to_perturb_annealing(memory_cells) ycoord_k_to_perturb_annealing(memory_cells)],vector_k_to_perturb_annealing(memory_cells),'plotit',false,'nrbins',50,'anisotropy',true);
variogram_k_to_perturb_annealing=struct2cell(variogram_k_to_perturb_annealing);
gamma_k_to_perturb_annealing=variogram_k_to_perturb_annealing{1};
theta_k_to_perturb_annealing=(variogram_k_to_perturb_annealing{2})*(180/pi);
h_k_to_perturb_annealing=variogram_k_to_perturb_annealing{4};


%% Optimization and Perturbation

weight=2;
obj_fun=((gamma_perm_sampledata-gamma_k_to_perturb_annealing).^ weight)+((k_geomean-k_eff).^weight);
```

Comment: what's the question? Also, if this is related to your previous question, you might want to make sure gamma_perm_sampledata is a double (not a matrix) otherwise obj_fun will have a lot on it's plate (i.e. get the matrix norm)

Comment: Hi Rasman: This question is indeed related to my previous question, but this is the solution to that problem and I am kind of getting stuck in `k_to_perturb_annealing=fminsearch(delta_obj,k_to_perturb_annealing_initial);` and I am getting this error: `??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> fminsearch at 195
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Error in ==> optimizing_by_perturbing_SISIM_perm at
31
k_to_perturb_annealing=fminsearch(delta_obj,k_to_perturb_annealing_initial); `

Comment: Rasman: Please the updated question above with error message and where I am getting stuck. Thanks!

Comment: what's at line 31 of your code?

Comment: @Rasman: That's just a comment. I am storing the coordinates of each value of `k_to_perturb_annealing`. That's not of much importance to optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is

```
obj_fun=((gamma_perm_sampledata-gamma_k_to_perturb_annealing).^ weight)+((k_geomean-k_eff).^weight);
```

you need to change ((gamma_perm_sampledata-gamma_k_to_perturb_annealing).^ weight) into a scalar as k_geomean is a scalar

try to use (norm((gamma_perm_sampledata-gamma_k_to_perturb_annealing),2)^weight), or (norm((gamma_perm_sampledata-gamma_k_to_perturb_annealing),'fro')^weight) or ...

Comment: Thanks Rasman, its working. Though I am not sure if it has got stuck or its taking time to run. I just stopped the program in between. Do you know how much time it could take to get results? Thanks!

Comment: it's a huge matrix so it will likely take a while. One option is that you can limit the iteration count and then use the output as your new initializing matrix. Another option is start with a 'tic' and then end with a toc in your function (which will tell you how long each iteration is taking). FWIW, it's the reason I have a beast of machine for these computations

Comment: Thanks Rasman. But I am not using any iteration count in my program in order to call `fminsearch(delta_obj,k_to_perturb_annealing_initial);`. I am calling this only once. Can you elaborate a little bit how I can use those techniques that you have specified in order to check how much time its taking to run. By this time my program is still busy running.

Comment: Rasman: The program was busy running till now. After Ctrl+C, this is where it stopped: `??? Operation terminated by user during ==>
sortrows at 100

In ==> unique at 195
            [b,ndx] = sortrows(a);

In ==> variogram at 131
[m,m] = unique(sort(iid(:,[1 2]),2),'rows');

In ==> gibbs_sampling_sisim_well_testing at 71
variogram_k_to_perturb_annealing=variogram([xcoord_k_to_perturb_annealing(memory_cells) ycoord_k_to_perturb_annealing(memory_cells)],vector_k_to_perturb_annealing(memory_cells),'plotit',false,'nrbins`

Comment: 1. create a function opti= optimset('MaxIter', 100) (you can change 100 for something else. then fminsearch(fun, xo, opti). If you want to know how long it takes to run your function with each execution go to the file that holds your fnuction. the second line (i.e. after the fct definition) put `tic`. Finally add `toc` at the end of that function

Comment: @Rasman: Do I make `optimset` as a new function? I did, then what value to give for `MaxIter`? Also, do I call `optimset` and write `tic` and `toc` in my code where I am using `fminsearch(fun, xo, opti)`?

Comment: optimset is already defined: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/optimset.html. tic/toc should go in the function itself (i.e. not in the code which has fminsearch). See how long one iteration takes then ask yourself how long you are willing to let the code run

Comment: That works Rasman. So this `Elapsed time is 4.764987 seconds.` represents the time taken by one iteration? How do we know how many iterations it would take to converge, i.e. to give the solution?

Comment: Also, after each iteration the `obj_fun` value is not converging. Its varying between `4.1080e+012` and `4.1105e+012` by this time I have the code running.

Comment: I don't know how much time it will take, but it sounds like it will be taking hours or even days(!). My advice is to format your code and make it more efficient: use the Matlab Profiler, and don't do iterations on constants (for instance don't load data in the function but pass the pertinent results to the function so you only do most calculations once, e.g. xcoord_k_to_perturb_annealing can be calculated before the function call)... I'm sure you can bring down that time if you streamline the called function.

Comment: also, for the sake of patience, add and display a counter in the function instead of tic/toc once you have the code fully optimised: in your main script define a global counter, set to zero, then in the function do `counter = counter + 1` (without the semicolon)

Comment: When will the iterations stop? After optimizing the code, I am getting one constant value of `obj_fun` as `3.6295e+005` after each elapsed time. Is `fminsearch` perturbing/changing my `k_to_perturb_annealing` values in order to achieve minimum `obj_fun`? I'm not sure what its doing.

Comment: it will keep on going until the output tolerance in below a set threshold *see the optimset definition) or it reaches the maximum number of iterations, and yes it's obj_fun finds the best k_to_perturb_annealing value